# What is $|\{n\in N:n\mid p^2q\}|$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

$$|\{n\in N:n\mid p^2q\}|$$
$p$ is an odd prime number, $q$ is a prime number and $p$ does not equal $q$.

I dont understand what they're asking me to find, is it to find a value of $n$ that divides into $p^2q$?

I need all the help i can get here, very new to this
thanks

Comment: No; they are asking you to compute the number of dicisors of $p^2q$.

Comment: how do you do that?

Comment: I would count them.

Comment: i mean how would i work out the divisors in the first place?

Comment: @Chloe $p,q$ are prime numbers, so let's do an example: how many different numbers divide $3^2\cdot 2$? What about $5^2\cdot 7$?

Answer (score 1):

What they ask for is in set-builder notation: *the number* of natural numbers $n$ such that $n$ divides $p^2q$, or the number of divisors of $p^2q$, or just $\tau(p^2q)$.

$p$ does not have to be an odd prime for us to figure this out, just that $p\ne q$. There are six divisors:
$$1,p,p^2,q,pq,p^2q$$
So the required answer is 6.

Comment: the question says the p is an odd prime, or does is it not matter?

Comment: @Chloe This turns out to be irrelevant (at least to the problem at hand).

Comment: ok thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

The inner part of that expression 
 inside the curly braces
means the set of all positive integers which divide
$p^2q$.

The outer part with "|...|"
means to count the number of elements in that set.

The whole expression is asking you to count the number of divisors of $p^2q$.